# Add Badge if product is on specific category on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I need, for specific category, on single product page and category page and every other page, a custom badge. So if product is on category ID 14 display badge name "Premium" (of product is new or in sale must be appears also this badge unit "Premium").

I try to do this but not work (I put on products-list.tpl).

```
{assign var='premium' value=0}                
    {foreach Product::getProductCategories($smarty.get.id_product) as $category}
       {if in_array($category, 14)}
          {assign var='premium' value=1}
       {/if}
 {/foreach}
{if $associated==1}
  <div class =" origine-GB "> </ div>
{/if}
```

Not work :(

Answer (score 0):

First I must say this is quick hack and that proper way would be to make a module with custom hook maybe. But here is code you are aiming got.

In `product-list.tpl` add

```
                    {assign var='premium' value=0}
                    {if in_array('14', Product::getProductCategories($product.id_product))}
                        {assign var='premium' value=1}
                    {/if}
                    {if $premium==1}
                      <div class =" origine-GB "> </ div>
                    {/if}
```

And for`product.tpl` use

```
            {assign var='premium' value=0}                
            {if in_array('14', Product::getProductCategories($product->id))}
            {assign var='premium' value=1}
            {/if}
            {if $premium==1}
              <div class =" origine-GB"> </ div>
            {/if}
```

You were setting `premium` variable but use `associated` later.

Also `in_array` goes other way around [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).